# Is there an API to map a vSphere JSON Result to an appropriate Java Object?

Tags: java, json, rest, vmware, vsphere

I am trying to use the REST API of vSphere to get information about our virtual machines. I already connected to the server using the provided REST API and
I got a JSON Result from a REST request. The vSphere JSON result looks like this:

```
{"value":[{
        "hot_add_increment_size_MiB": 8,
        "size_MiB": 1,
        "hot_add_enabled": false,
        "hot_add_limit_MiB": 51258
     }]
}
```

Now I want to convert this JSON String to an appropriate Class.
The problem, I am actually facing is, that it can be a very complex JSON result.

My question is: Is there an API from VMWare, I can use to solve my problem?
Every hint is appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: *I am actually facing is, that it can be a very complex JSON result (...)* Why don't you map *only* the properties you need and ignore the others?

Comment: Well, I am not sure how to explain it. There is a lot of information I am retrieving and sometimes the fields are filled, sometimes not, sometimes the whole object isn't available in the JSON result. Then I am getting exceptions. this is realy hard to handle, so I thought there is maybe an easy way to solve this problem, e.g. with an existing API...

Comment: Here you can see the structure of the REST result: https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/1cd28284-3b72-4885-9e31-d1c6d9e26686/71ef7304-a6c9-43b3-a3cd-868b2c236c81/doc/operations/com/vmware/vcenter/vm.get-operation.html

Comment: And do you need *all properties?*

Comment: Sorry, I should read the API more carefully, before asking questions. There are different JSON structures. For each request you have a diffferent JSON result. So you need different pojos to map the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. There is schema published by VMware. It might not exist.

You may be able to get what you want with this API (disclaimer: I am the author):
https://github.com/DoubleCloudInc/vim-rest-api/

The schema is the same as vSphere API, so you can use the vijava data objects as your Java objects. http://vijava.sf.net. Again, I am the author.